# Subdomain with Subdirectory 404 page

Tags: url, subdomain, http-status-code-404, subdirectory

On most websites, with subdomains, when I go to forum.example.com I get the correct page but when I go to example.com/forum I get a 404 page. Can someone tell me how they do that? Do they point the subdomain to a different folder in the root? Like "forum." is pointed to "afolder" than of "forum"?

Regards

Comment: there are many possibilities, but usually the subdomain would be a completely separate entity handling http requests on its own

Answer (score 0):

With your web host (assuming you are not hosting it) they will normally have an option to add sub-domains, this will depend on whether your plan has this included and if it does, there will sometimes be a limited amount.

When you make it there will be some kind of management system to add files to the new section on your site.

Answer (score 0):

The subdomain can point to ANY folder on a site. Shared hosting sites usually have access to a program like Cpanel where you can direct where the subdomain goes. Web server operators who use linux and apache can generally modify a file like http.conf to point domains/subdomains to whereever.